# std::map both costume compare functor and function/ lambda error

Tags: c++, c++11, compare, stdmap

I have the following:

```
inputs:    
    Map1["Ram"] = 8;
    Map1["Aam"] = 8;
    Map1["Some"] = 2;
    Map1["He"] = 5;
    Map1["He"] = 6;
```

The expected output after insertion to the `std::map<std::string, int>` should be:

```
Output:
    "Some" 2  
    "He"   5
    "He"   6
    "Aam"  8
```

Please note that:

1. sorting is according to the **values**, not keys.
2. the input `Map1["Ram"] = 8;`  has overwritten by the next input `Map1["Aam"] = 8;`

**Approach 1**: Using a functor I was thinking to manage it. I have got this two errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in MyTestProgram (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_map.h||In instantiation of 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = int; _Compare = compare_functor; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':|
D:\Programming\C++\CPP Programs\MyTestProgram\MyTestProgram.cpp|22|required from here|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_map.h|511|error: no match for call to '(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, compare_functor>::key_compare {aka compare_functor}) (std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, compare_functor>::key_type&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)'|
D:\Programming\C++\CPP Programs\MyTestProgram\MyTestProgram.cpp|12|note: candidate: bool compare_functor::operator()(const T&, const T&) const|
D:\Programming\C++\CPP Programs\MyTestProgram\MyTestProgram.cpp|12|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, compare_functor>::key_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const T& {aka const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&}'|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_tree.h||In instantiation of 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_lower_bound(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr, const _Key&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; |
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_tree.h|1187|required from 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::lower_bound(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = compare_functor; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfVa|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_map.h|1234|required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::lower_bound(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = int; _Compare = compare_functor; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_map.h|509|required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = int; _Compare = compare_functor; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'|
Program.cpp|22|required from here|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_tree.h|1872|error: no match for call to '(compare_functor) (const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)'|
Program.cpp|12|note: candidate: bool compare_functor::operator()(const T&, const T&) const|
Program.cpp|12|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to 'const T& {aka const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&}'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 7 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

**Approach 2**: The same logic I implemented with a lambda and I have got almost the same errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in MyTestProgram (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_map.h||In instantiation of 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = int; _Compare = bool (*)(const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&); _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std:|
Program.cpp|37|required from here|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_map.h|511|error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&' from expression of type 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int, bool (*)(const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&)>::key_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_tree.h||In instantiation of 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_lower_bound(std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Base_ptr, const _Key&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; |
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_tree.h|1187|required from 'std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::lower_bound(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Val = std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; _Compare = bool (*)(const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&); _Alloc = |
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_map.h|1234|required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::lower_bound(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = int; _Compare = bool (*)(const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&); _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::ba|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_map.h|509|required from 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type&&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = int; _Compare = bool (*)(const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&, const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&); _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::map<_|
Program.cpp|37|required from here|
d:\mingw\include\c++\7.3.0\bits\stl_tree.h|1872|error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>&' from expression of type 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 7 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have referred many answers online. But most of them were considering either Key type or Value type while comparing using the functor/ lambda, which was not my case. I would like to compare **both Value and Key compared** while inserting to the map.

Can anybody explain to me **why these implementations fail**?

Secondly, what I should have done to get above result while inserting(**PS:** I would like to still keep `string` as my key to the map and if it is possible, I do not want any temporary maps to do this result.)?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

typedef std::pair<std::string, int> T;
typedef bool(*compare_functional_type)(const T&, const T&);

// Way - 1: using functor
struct compare_functor
{
   bool operator()(const T& A ,const T& B)const
   {
      return std::tie(A.second, A.first) < std::tie(B.second, B.first);
      // OR in other-words:
      //return (A.second == B.second) ? A.first < B.first : A.second < B.second;
   };
};
int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, int, compare_functor> Map1;
   Map1["Ram"] = 8;
   Map1["Aam"] = 8;
   Map1["Some"] = 2;
   Map1["He"] = 5;
   Map1["He"] = 6;

   // Way - 2: using lambdas and function pointers
   compare_functional_type Lambda = [](const T& A, const T& B)
   {
      return std::tie(A.second, A.first) < std::tie(B.second, B.first);
      // OR in other-words:
      //return (A.second == B.second) ? A.first < B.first : A.second < B.second;
   };

   std::map<std::string, int, compare_functional_type> Map2(Lambda);
   Map2["Ram"] = 8;
   Map2["Aam"] = 8;
   Map2["Some"] = 2;
   Map2["He"] = 5;
   Map2["He"] = 6;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you want `std::map<int, std::string>`.

Comment: You clearly treat "values" as keys and "keys" as values. Just use `map<int, string>` and be done with it.

Comment: `std::map` uses its comparison predicate to compare keys, not {key, value} pairs. Your predicate assumes the latter, and has no chance of working.

Comment: @Jarod42 like I mentioned in the question, is it possible to keep `string` as my key itself? and have the same result?

Comment: You might wrap it in a class to have derived syntax...

Comment: That's just not what `std::map` means. If you want it sorted by the `int`, sort before outputting.

Comment: @Jarod42 could you get me an example question from SO? I don't know how to specifically look that case.

Comment: @PasserBy I can easily do it with `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>` and latter just remove the duplicates using remove-erase ideom. But latter for a search/ `std::vector::find` will give always leaner time lookup, whereas using the `std::map` I can simply get it with log(n). That is why I wanted to have it with `std::map`

Comment: You can do it in log(n) with a sorted vector as well, just use bisection to search through it (such as `std::lower_bound`).

Comment: You are asking a container to be simultaneously sorted with two orderings. That cannot be done with `std::map`, and neither with `std::vector`. You'll have to use something else.

Comment: Nothing in your problem statement requires anything more than a plain vanilla `map<int, string>`. I don't understand why you are fighting this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map<int, std::string>` is what you want.

To have your inverted syntax, you might use wrapper, something like:

```
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(std::map<int, std::string>& m, const std::string& s) : m(m), s(s) {}

    void operator =(int k) { m[k] = s; }
private:
    std::map<int, std::string>& m;
    std::string s;
};

class InvertedMap
{
public:
    Wrapper operator[](const std::string& s) { return {m, s}; }

    auto begin() const { return m.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return m.end(); }
private:
    std::map<int, std::string> m;  
};
```

And then:

```
InvertedMap Map1;
Map1["Ram"] = 8;
Map1["Aam"] = 8;
Map1["Some"] = 2;
Map1["He"] = 5;
Map1["He"] = 6;

for (const auto& p : Map1) {
    std::cout << p.second << " " << p.first << std::endl;
}

// Output:
// Some 2
// He 5
// He 6
// Aam 8
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VeX7AS)

Comment: Wow.... that's really amazing. This is what I want. Extra up for the great idea and effort. :)